# Why sorting list is working for firefox but not working on chrome?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Once the *th* clicked then the function below will be invoked. This is working on Firefox, but not working on Chrome.

```
    handleSort(event) {
        let id = event.target.id;

        this.setState(prev => {
            console.log(prev);
            return { 
                [id]: !prev[id],
                books: prev.books.sort((a, b) =>
                    prev[id] ? a[id] < b[id] : a[id] > b[id]
                )
            };
        });
    }
```

Comment: What testing have you done? Is there anything being spit to your console with an error in Chrome at all?

Comment: And why sort in place, modifying state directly?

Comment: I'm guessing your issue is related to [Sorting in JavaScript: Shouldn't returning a boolean be enough for a comparison function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24080785) but not sure why it would work in firefox ?

Comment: The way you've implemented the comparator works for Firefox because (perhaps) the Firefox engine assumes the `boolean` values `true` and `false` as `-1` and `1` respectively. Chrome's implementation seems to be more sensitive, in that it explicitly expects you to return one of `-1`, `0` or `1` from the `sort` comparator. It'd be nice to know if there are any errors in the Chrome console.

Comment: @MananShah There is no error from the Chrome console and that's why I am here. But I can research on thanks to you guys.

Comment: @DaveNewton what other way are you recommneding because it's been a few days since I started learning ReactJs. Bear with my stupidity.

Comment: @MananShah hey you are right. Once I put another comparision for equal it's working beautifully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you've implemented the comparator works for Firefox because (perhaps) the Firefox engine assumes the boolean values `true` and `false` as `1` and `-1` respectively. Chrome's implementation seems to be more sensitive, in that it explicitly expects you to return one of `-1`, `0` or `1` from the sort comparator.

You might wanna change the comparison inside the `sort()` to have it working on all browsers.